# Null are not matching in Join in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In the below query 
 c.EXTRA_CALLOFF_FLAG = a.EXTRA_CALLOFF_FLAG it has two matchings one is Y and other value is NULL

```
SELECT PICKUP_WK_NBR,REGION_CD,GLOBAL_DUNS_NBR,GLOBAL_SUPPLIER_NAME,a.EXTRA_CALLOFF_FLAG,
       nvl((SELECT sum(c.CALLOFF_QTY)
               FROM GMMT_OWNER.OR_SA_ATTAIN_DTL_T c join GMMT_OWNER.OR_SA_INCOTERMS_T d
                 on
                  c.SUPPLIER_INCOTERMS_1_CD = d.INCOTERMS_CD
               WHERE
                  d.PICKUP_ARRIVAL_FLAG='P'  and
                  a.PICKUP_WK_NBR = c.PICKUP_WK_NBR and
                  a.GLOBAL_DUNS_NBR = c.GLOBAL_DUNS_NBR and
                  a.REGION_CD=c.REGION_CD and 
                  c.EXTRA_CALLOFF_FLAG = a.EXTRA_CALLOFF_FLAG and
                  a.SUPPLIER_INCOTERMS_1_CD = c.SUPPLIER_INCOTERMS_1_CD
                 ),0) total_items_ordered
FROM
                GMMT_OWNER.OR_SA_ATTAIN_DTL_T a join GMMT_OWNER.OR_SA_INCOTERMS_T b on
                a.SUPPLIER_INCOTERMS_1_CD = b.INCOTERMS_CD
WHERE
                b.PICKUP_ARRIVAL_FLAG='P' and
                (a.PICKUP_WK_NBR between '201301' AND '201301')  and
                a.SUPPLIER_INCOTERMS_1_CD IN ('EXW')        and 
                a.GLOBAL_DUNS_NBR IN ('43898092') and
                a.REGION_CD IN ('AP')                     
GROUP BY
                PICKUP_WK_NBR,REGION_CD,GLOBAL_DUNS_NBR,GLOBAL_SUPPLIER_NAME,a.EXTRA_CALLOFF_FLAG,a.SUPPLIER_INCOTERMS_1_CD
ORDER BY a.PICKUP_WK_NBR;
```

it is giving wrong result. I am not sure whether the NULL between inner and outer table join are matching?

Comment: . . Any comparison to NULL -- with the exception of `is null` -- is false.  So even `NULL = NULL` evaluates to false.  If you are trying to do explicit NULL comparisons, either include `is NULL` or `coalesce()` in the `on` clause.

Comment: Pls can u suggest how to add coalesce in on clause on the above query??

Comment: . . What fields can take on NULL values?

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon stated in the comment, you cannot treat null like a value.

You should possibly rethink joining on a column that can be null, though.

It sounds like you want to treat it as a possible value, though.  One way to do that is with nvl().

Here is one way to make your join condition have a value.  The strings between the quotes must be the same on both sides of the equals.

Change

```
c.EXTRA_CALLOFF_FLAG = a.EXTRA_CALLOFF_FLAG
```

to

```
nvl(c.EXTRA_CALLOFF_FLAG, 'null') = nvl(a.EXTRA_CALLOFF_FLAG, 'null')
```

Comment: cool.  much better. lnnvl() returns true if the parameters are false or null.